# Interact with Chart JS with Python Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, highcharts

I'm trying to press the buttons on this chart JS on the webpage https://icomarks.com/ico/online. I tried both by xpath, full xpath and JS path without succeeding. In the example you'll find my attempt to press the "All" button as below: [image: here]

Thank you!

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url='https://icomarks.com/ico/online'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# xpath
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="highcharts-34i2crn-1324"]/svg/g[23]/g[1]/g[7]')))
button.click()

# full xpath
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/svg/g[23]/g[1]/g[7]')))
button.click()

# JS path
element=driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#highcharts-7gub67p-1324 > svg > g.highcharts-range-selector-group > g.highcharts-range-selector-buttons > g.highcharts-no-tooltip.highcharts-button.highcharts-button-pressed")')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG elements in Selenium require a distinct approach for locating them compared to regular HTML elements because they are constructed using XML instead of HTML. In order to find SVG elements, we can use the name() xpath function

For elements which are part of svg you can build a xpath like below and then click on them
for e.g. All button you can use below

```
button=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                     '//div[@class="companyGraph"]//div[@class="highcharts-container "]//*[name()="g" and '
                     '@class="highcharts-range-selector-group"]//*[name()="text" and text()="All"]')
```

Full code , you can change option to Click below by changing text value

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://icomarks.com/ico/online'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

valueToClick = "3m"
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                             '//div[@class="companyGraph"]//div[@class="highcharts-container "]//*[name()="g" and '
                             f'@class="highcharts-range-selector-group"]//*[name()="text" and text()="{valueToClick}"]')
button.click()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you be so kind to tell me how I can extract the path you used with Chrome inspect tool?

Comment: Instead of extracting it, I constructed it by examining the developer tools and manually writing the xpath. Although you can try right-clicking and selecting "copy js path," this method often results in an unreliable locator that may fail in the future if any dynamic attributes are involved. For a tutorial on using XPath with SVG, please refer to the following resource  [svg](https://www.inviul.com/svg-elements-xpath-selenium/)

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts creates a dynamic id for a container, so using something like `highcharts-34i2crn-1324` will not help to find the proper element.

However, you can access the button and other chart properties by using the global `Highcharts` variable. For example:

```
Highcharts.charts[1].rangeSelector.buttons[5].element.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```